# OctoberCMS Media Manager: cannot create new folders

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm using the last version of October. I have a strange issue. When I try to create a new folder in the Media Manager, it says : "The file type used is blocked for security reasons."

I have no idea why. Could you help me?

Comment: what is the name of the folder ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My company makes multiple October instances per week and this is the first time it's happened.

As a work around for now: I SSH'd onto the server and manually created the directories with `mkdir` - just be sure to set the right read, write and execute permissions.

Comment: Yes, if you create the folder manually, it works… 
I cannot understand that…

Comment: May be something to do with the security updates introduced in build 413 (https://octobercms.com/support/article/rn-8) but there's not a lot of detail about what changed.

Comment: Yes, well done : https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2814